# Getting all email from the Outlook Email Rest API, but spam

Tags: outlook, outlook-restapi

I'm trying to get all the emails from a user from the Outlook Email Rest API.

- looks like the API only allows to retrieve 50 emails max : no way to retrieve more ?
- I need "ALL" emails (not only the one in the inbox). But if we parse all emails, we have a problem : indeed, it includes emails that are in the Spam folder, and there is no "tag" on these emails in the API that show they are spam. We found 2 workarounds :

  - first scanning all the spam emails, save the ids, then ignore them when we scan for all emails
  - check the spam folder id, and check that the parentId of the emails is not the spam folder id. It breaks if your contacts are in a subfolder of the spam folder, but who creates folder in spams, right ?
  - any way to get on an email a flag that it's spam ? There are other flags, like IsRead / IsDraft, but not this one

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

> looks like the API only allows to retrieve 50 emails max : no way to retrieve more ?

Yes you can get more. You need to use [paging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#page-results) to get the next set of results. There should be an `@odata.nextLink` property in the response that you can do a GET on to get the next page.

> I need "ALL" emails (not only the one in the inbox). But if we parse all emails, we have a problem : indeed, it includes emails that are in the Spam folder, and there is no "tag" on these emails in the API that show they are spam.

Yes this is correct. I think I would do the second option here, match the ID of the Junk folder with the `ParentId` of the messages.